# Staying on page depending on value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to stay on the same page if the login (`data.login != 1`) is incorrect , I tried with `preventDefault` but that's not working. Can anyone help me ?

```
$(document).on('submit', '#login', function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.login === 1) {
                $.mobile.changePage("<?php echo site_url('redirect/overview'); ?>");
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The page will submit before the result of ajax call is being received in `success` as you have `asyn` call, You can `e.preventDefault()` before ajax call and call `submit` on success.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#login', function(e) {         
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);            
        var url = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.login === 1) {
                    $.mobile.changePage("<?php echo site_url('redirect/overview'); ?>");
                }
                else {
                    $('#submitButtonId')[0].submit();
                }
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: `$('#submitButtonId').submit();` (or click()) will trigger same handler again, you want: `form[0].submit();` to submit the FORM. BTW, i think `submitButtonId` is the submit button, i guess

Comment: When the else block is called , I need to stay on the page (not submit a form)? How to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @David then do nothing, remove `else` block

Comment: Well yes but when submitting with incorrect login data it's still going to my controller. My controller uses json to return a response to the ajax (success). It's 1 when credentials are true else 0 (=>data.login)